# Container ifconfig & nslookup IPs don't match

Tags: docker

I'm running a container called "front-end". Other containers communicate with this container by using the name front-end which gets resolved into the containers IP address. I noticed something that doesn't make sense to me about this container.

When I shell into the container and run "ifconfig", I see one IP address. When I run "nslookup front-end" I see another IP address. I would have though that these two IPs should have matched. See my terminal output below:

I'm doing this in swarm-mode. Here is how I start the containers:

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --name first --network my-network aarch64/ubuntu:16.04 sleep 99999999999999999
docker service create --with-registry-auth --name second --network my-network aarch64/ubuntu:16.04 sleep 99999999999999999
```

Terminal output to confirm the containers are up and running:

```
odroid@odroid64-cluster4:~/ssd/weaveworksdemo$ docker service ls
ID            NAME    REPLICAS  IMAGE                 COMMAND
7v04cpi9b8uq  second  1/1       aarch64/ubuntu:16.04  sleep 99999999999999999
cru6diqlv5on  first   1/1       aarch64/ubuntu:16.04  sleep 99999999999999999
```

swarm service and docker PS commands

```
odroid@odroid64-cluster4:~/ssd/weaveworksdemo$ docker service ps first
ID                         NAME     IMAGE                 NODE               DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE          ERROR
4dqy376icyi8fow1y1owwjzj0  first.1  aarch64/ubuntu:16.04  odroid64-cluster3  Running        Running 2 minutes ago
odroid@odroid64-cluster4:~/ssd/weaveworksdemo$ docker service ps second
ID                         NAME      IMAGE                 NODE               DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE          ERROR
aurs8nznz35to7pjcikn9903h  second.1  aarch64/ubuntu:16.04  odroid64-cluster4  Running        Running 2 minutes ago
odroid@odroid64-cluster4:~/ssd/weaveworksdemo$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
cd28f6ec30e1        aarch64/ubuntu:16.04      "sleep 99999999999999"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                 second.1.aurs8nznz35to7pjcikn9903h
```

As can be seen. First is running on cluster3, and second it running on cluster4.

Now, let's take a look at the my-network inspection:

```
odroid@odroid64-cluster4:~/ssd/weaveworksdemo$ docker network inspect my-network
[
    {
        "Name": "my-network",
        "Id": "3kjlgo564nkmnccliuz7rlxa3",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.10.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.10.0.2"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "cd28f6ec30e1ab33c09ef20ef4ee3968d7e7d71f83608a7ebd995986f9c7a049": {
                "Name": "second.1.aurs8nznz35to7pjcikn9903h",
                "EndpointID": "bf3089daf09a9de1a9b245807d8b3cb3cbee1d3e28887f8f8b5a375ba72d9e18",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:0a:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "10.10.0.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "258",
            "encrypted": ""
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

The reason you only see container service "second" is because I am shelled into cluster4. If I were to shell into cluster3, and run the network inspect command, I would see the service "first". This is how network overlays work in Docker. **Notice the IP is 10.10.0.6**

Alright, let's shell into "second" and run ifconfig, and nslookup.

```
odroid@odroid64-cluster4:~/ssd/weaveworksdemo$ docker exec -ti second.1.aurs8nznz35to7pjcikn9903h bash
root@cd28f6ec30e1:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0a:0a:00:06
          inet addr:10.10.0.6  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:aff:fe0a:6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1424  Metric:1
          RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1038 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:12:00:03
          inet addr:172.18.0.3  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe12:3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:36597121 (36.5 MB)  TX bytes:443087 (443.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:4096  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:876 (876.0 B)  TX bytes:876 (876.0 B)

root@cd28f6ec30e1:/# nslookup second
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   second
Address: 10.10.0.5
```

Notice how ifconfig shows 10.10.0.6, and resolving the name "front-end" returns 10.10.0.5. Also, notice how network inspect matches up with the ifconfig output.

Can anyone explain why this is the case? I take back that this is all working. Having some issues with connectivity between nodes, not sure if this might have something to do with it.

One other note, I'm running two containers with different names, but I see the same thing even if I run a single container.

Comment: Are you actually interacting with the `front-end` container in this example?  Please edit the answer to show a `docker ps` first, followed by whatever command you're using to access the `front-end` container.

Comment: Are you running multiple `front-end`s with Docker Compose?

Comment: No, a single instance of front-end. I'll have to update with the "docker ps" command a bit later. In the middle of something else right now.

Comment: Ok, updated with much more details.

Answer (score 1):

It's about [Docker Virtual-IP](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#bypass-the-routing-mesh-for-a-swarm-service)

For example:

- You name a service `redis-service` in your compose file.
- You can connect to that redis server via `redis-service`.
- If you replicate this redis service to five instances, then which ip address should `redis-service` resolve to?
- `redis-service` will be resolved to a virtual ip, and five redis instances will be load balanced by this virutal ip.
- It's the same even you have only one instance.

Comment: Is there a way to list the services available from within the container?